# Low Pass Ideal Filter implementing using matlab 2014a

Tags: matlab, signals, filtering, bandwidth

here I have to sound signals - one is a male speech signal and the other is a noise signal- , I have added them together - call it signal "mix" -  and now I'm asked to filter it so that noise is removed and what remain is only the male speech signal.
After analyzing the graphs of male speech and noise in time and frequency domain

**Time Domain** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5iqc.jpg): https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5frew6f0qlbae5/filteres%20signal.jpg?dl=0

[image]

**Frequency Domain**

[image]

I observed that the max freq of male speech is a little less that the min freq of noise, so I made a low pass filter - using rect function - and filter it in frequency domain.

**Ideal Low Pass Filter**

[image]

I plotted the resulted signal in both frequency and time domain, the graph in frequency domain is the same as the male speech graph in frequency domain but in time domain it's not exactly the same

**Filtered Signal**

[image]
and I noticed the change also when I sounded the resulted signal. 
Any help please to know why the filtered signal is not exactly as the original male speech?

*P.S: I know that filtering in this way is not sufficient but currently this is how we are supposed to do it in our report in my course.

**Here is my Code:**

```
[voice,Fs] = audioread ('hamid1.wav');
[noise,Fs] = audioread ('noise.wav');
voice(55126: 131072)=0 % to add both voice and noise signal together their dimensio must agree
mix = voice + noise; % the mixed signal

%vp = audioplayer(voice,Fs);
%play(vp);
%-- data for plotting voice --%
iFs = 1/Fs;
voiceLen = length(voice);
voiceF0 = 1/(iFs*voiceLen);
f_voice = 0:voiceF0: (voiceLen-1)*voiceF0;
t_voice = 0:iFs:(voiceLen-1)*iFs;
mag_voice = abs(fft(voice));

%-- data for plotting noise --%
noiseLen = length(noise);
noiseF0 = 1/(iFs*noiseLen);
f_noise = 0:noiseF0: (noiseLen-1)*noiseF0;
t_noise = 0:iFs:(noiseLen-1)/Fs;
mag_noise = abs(fft(noise));
%--------------------------------------------%

%-- data for plotting mix --%
mixLen = length(mix);
mixF0 = 1/(iFs*mixLen);
f_mix= 0:mixF0: (mixLen-1)*mixF0;
t_mix = 0:iFs:(mixLen-1)/Fs;
mag_mix = abs(fft(mix));

%-- plotting voice speech, noise and mix in frequency domain --%
figure(1);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(f_voice,mag_voice);
title('voice speech in frequency domain');
xlabel('frequency'); ylabel('Magnitude');
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(f_noise,mag_noise);
title('noise in frequency domain');
xlabel('frequency'); ylabel('Magnitude');
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(f_mix,mag_mix);
title('mix signal in frequency domain');
xlabel('frequency'); ylabel('Magnitude')

%-- plotting voice speech, noise and mix in time domain --%
figure(2);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t_voice,voice);
title('voice speech in time domain');
xlabel('time'); ylabel('Amplitude');
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t_noise,noise);
title('noise in time domain');
xlabel('time'); ylabel('Amplitude');
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t_mix, mix);
title('mix signal in time domain');
xlabel('time'); ylabel('Amplitude')

%-- design the bandpass filter --
rect = 1*(f_mix>=0 & f_mix <3000);
rect2= rect+0*(f_mix>=3000 & f_mix <5482);
%-- plotting the ideal filter --%
figure(3)
plot(f_mix, rect2,'linewidth',2);
title('bandpass ideal filter');
xlabel('frequency'); ylabel('Magnitude')
axis([0 11000 0 1.5])

%-- Filtering the mix signal to extract voice speech without noise --%
filtered = rect2.*mag_mix'
filteredT = ifft(filtered)

figure(4)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(f_mix, filtered)
title('Filtered signal in frequency domain')
xlabel('frequency')
ylabel('Magnitude')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t_mix, real(filteredT))
title('Filtered signal in time domain')
xlabel('time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
%-------------------------------------------%
filtSig = audioplayer(filteredT,Fs)
play(filtSig)
```

Comment: The pictures don't show up. Probably best to check the hyperlinks.

Comment: @am304 I have added links to the pics as well I hope it will show now

Comment: Here's the message when I clik on the links: "Error (403).
It seems you don't belong here! You should probably sign in. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home."

Comment: @am304 aha I see, I'll work on it, maybe because it's dropbox links.

Comment: Confirmed.  Links are dead.

Comment: @rayryeng I don't know how to fix this issue this is my first time to upload images on this site, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Download the images onto your computer, then use the upload image feature when editing your question.

Comment: @AMH9, the links do not works because of permissions. In Dropbox, you have to create 'links' to the pictures you want to share with other users.

Comment: @Hoki can someone please check if the images show now?

Comment: Images work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint - is an ideal filter realizable? What's the inverse fourier transform of your ideal low pass filter? It's been a while since I've looked at this stuff but I don't think you're getting an error. Rather, you're seeing the effect of an overly rigid filter design.

Comment: Inverse fourier transform of my ideal filter would be the sinc function in time domain, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. So if you multiply by your ideal filter in the frequency domain, how does that translate to the time domain?

Comment: umm I think in time domain I will have to do convolution between the filter - sinc function - with the signal, but since the sinc function is not realizable in matlab as it goes to infinity, matlab cut it by default, and I think there is several types of windows - rect .. kaiser etc.. - to reach the most perfect filter.

Comment: I do understand the difference of doing filtering in time domain - windowing- and in frequency domain actually, I just thought that there is somthing wrong in this lowpass filter and could be made it better. Thank you for your time and  clarifications.

Comment: My point was that if you use an ideal lowpass filter in the frequency domain, you will end up smearing the signal and causing 'ringing' because, as you pointed out, the sinc function goes on to infinity and doesn't decay very quickly. [Please read the answer here.](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/589/should-i-use-ideal-or-non-ideal-filters-for-offline-filtering)